# Magento2 How to convert category url

Tags: magento2

If you have store **categories** in the backend and do not specify a URL key, Magento automatically generates it. 
However, Magento reacts with umlauts and special characters not as one expects.

From an "ä" an "a", from an "ö" an "o" and from a "ü" a "u". The same applies to the uppercase letters.

Example: [domain.com]/testö.html

I want like this: "ä" an "ae", "ö" an "oe", "ü" a "ue"

URL Example: [domain.com]/testoe.html

Answer (score 0):

You can change the url key after it has been automatically generated. Or you could just set it from the beginning.

See the docs for more details
http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/category-create.html

Comment: thanks fro your answer.
I have lots of categories, so you have any idea how can I do it programmatically using observer or  with override file.

Comment: hmm not sure, I would start by looking at `Magento\Catalog\Model\System\Config\Backend\Catalog\Url\Rewrite` and `Magento\UrlRewrite\Helper` and use xDebug to step through the code to see what was going on